# PHP foreach with two 'as'?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Hi there i am trying to combine two loops of foreach but i have a problem.

The problem is that the `<a href='$link'>` is same to all results but they must be different.

Here is the code that i am using:

```
<?php
$feed = file_get_contents('http://grabo.bg/rss/?city=&affid=16090');

$rss = simplexml_load_string($feed);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($feed);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('link');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    foreach($rss as $r){
        $title = $r->title;
        $content = $r->content;
        $link = $tag->getAttribute('href');
        echo "<a href='$link'>$title</a> <br> $content";
    }
}

?>
```

Where i my mistake? Why it's not working and how i make it work properly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: Is there an error message or something?

Comment: The problem is that the `<a href='$link'>` is same for all results.

Comment: You don't need two loops - either you use simplexml or DOMDocument.

Comment: The two loops you have are seemingly independent of each other, you are effectively creating a cross join. Use a debugger to see the values in each iteration if you still need to.

Comment: Give me example please. I don't get it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @TonnyStruck It would help if you could give example output of your code as well as the output you expect/want.

Answer (score 0):

Both loops were going through different resources so you are just simply cross joining all records in them.

This should work to get the data you need:

```
<?php
$feed = file_get_contents('http://grabo.bg/rss/?city=&affid=16090');
$rss = simplexml_load_string($feed);

foreach ($rss as $key => $entry) {
    if ($key == "entry")
    {
        $title = (string) $entry->title;
        $content = (string) $entry->content;
        $link = (string) $entry->link["href"];
        echo "<a href='$link'>$title</a><br />" . $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two more questions:
1 - How i can get the value that is contained inside the FIRST `<b></b> ` tag?

2 - How i can get and the decoded version of content without any html codes in it. Like pure clean text so can insert this version in my mysql table.

Comment: TO remove tags use strip_tags function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Okey, thanks! But how i can get the value of the `<b></b>` tags?

Comment: You can use preg_match on $content variable: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
You will have to know a bit of [regular experssions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to do that.